# Angular show more

Tags: angular, sass

I am trying to make a box with some text. When text is longer that 3 rows I would like cut off this text and show button * show more *. After clicking on this button will be show all text. And will be displayed button *show less*. When I press on button text is not showing.

There is my part of code. [My code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r99v8n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea is use a variable, e.g. toogle. You can use, e.g.

```
<p class="collapse" [class.show]="toogle">...</p>
<a class="collapse" [class.show]="toogle" 
                   (click)="toogle=!toogle"></a>
```

And play with .collapse:not(.show)

```
#module #collapseExample.collapse:not(.show) {
  display: block;
  height: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#module #collapseExample.collapsing {
  height: 3rem;
}

#module a.collapsed::after {
  content: '- Show Less';
}

#module a.collapsed:not(.show)::after {
  content: '+ Show More';
}
```